# I used fetch, but logs are only sent to vsc in the pending state

Tags: node.js, npm, promise, svelte

I'm trying to create a Microsoft account authentication function with msamc-npm. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/msamc)

I am developing with Svelte framework.

`+server.ts`

```
import type { RequestHandler } from "./$types";
import msamc from "msamc";


export const GET:RequestHandler = async ({ }) => {
    const req = await new msamc("APP-ID").Authenticate();

    return new Response((JSON.stringify(req)), {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
}
```

When I access this server, the server will wait in a pending state. (Later we will access the server using fetch.)
And send the following message to vsc terminal.
`To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://www.microsoft.com/link and enter the code 3XEPWECF to authenticate.`

When I go to that URL, enter the code, and log in, the pending state ends and a normal response comes.
But the problem is that messages containing code can only be viewed through the vsc terminal. It doesn't show up in the browser console.
I don't know how to access that code.

Also, is there a way to have the code automatically entered when I go to `https://www.microsoft.com/link`?